# Masstransit .NET: Is it possible to get the response in consume filter?

Tags: .net, messaging, masstransit

currently we used a set of consume filters in the Masstransit mediator, i.e. for validation, transactions etc. Between the API contoller and the Consumer we will use Request/Response

example in startup.cs:

```
services.AddMediator(x =>
                {
                    x.ConfigureMediator((context, cfg) =>
                    {
                        cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(LoggingConsumeFilter<>), context);
                        cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(ValidationFilter<>),context);
                        cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(ContextUserFilter<>),context);
                        cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(TransactionConsumeFilter<>),context);
                    });

                    x.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<GetDynFieldSectionModelQueryConsumer>();
```

Now I plan to add a new filter "AnonymisationConsumeFilter", the idea is that the filter will change the response after the consumer has finished. In our case the response should be made anonymous in certain cases (i.e. if the user has no access to VIP users).

The first idea was to add a filter like this:

```
public class AnonymisationConsumeFilter<TMessage> : IFilter<ConsumeContext<TMessage>>
    where TMessage : class
{
    private readonly ILogger<TMessage> logger;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly RoleAccessLevelOptions roleAccessLevelOptions;

    public AnonymisationConsumeFilter(ILogger<TMessage> logger, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IOptions<RoleAccessLevelOptions> roleAccessLevelOptions)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        this.roleAccessLevelOptions = roleAccessLevelOptions.Value;
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
        context.CreateFilterScope("make-anonymisation");
    }

    public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<TMessage> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<TMessage>> next)
    {
        var requestName = typeof(TMessage).Name;

        await next.Send(context);

        if (context.<how to get the response???> is not IResponseAccessLevel objectWithAccessLevel)
        {
            logger.LogWarning($"----- Make anonymisation for non IResponseAccessLevel objects is ignored, Request {requestName} {context.Message}");
        }
        else
        {
            var response = context.<how to get the response???>
   [...]

             AnonymisationHelper.MakeAnonymous(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I don't see a possibility to get the response from the consumer with the consume filter. The only possible I see at the moment is to use the message Payload. But how is it possible to modify the response in the filter and return to the caller?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

The response is actually *sent* back to the request originator, so in order to intercept the response you'd need to add a send filter. Scoped send filters are similar to consume filters, but built around `SendContext<T>`. The scope would be shared between consume and send filters.

Also, you could add something to the payload in the consume filter prior to sending it on to the consumer, and then in the send filter, check if a `ConsumeContext` is in the payload, and then request the custom payload from the *ConsumeContext* and use it in the send filter.

Comment: In the sendFilter I can now check for the correct response class and start to make anonymous. For unknown reason the send filter is called multiple times for the same response object. I could not figure out the reason for this.... currently I set a payload to ignore extra calls I don't need. Maybe this is due to Masstransit DI???